# How to filter map content by path

Tags: clojure

I want to select paths of a deeply nested map to keep.

For example:

```clj
{:a 1
 :b {:c [{:d 1 :e 1} 
         {:d 2 :e 2}]
     :f 1}
 :g {:h {:i 4 :j [1 2 3]}}}
```

I want to select by paths, like so:

```clj
(select-paths m [[:a] 
                 [:b :c :e]
                 [:b :f]
                 [:g :h :i]])
```

This would return

```clj
{:a 1
 :b {:c [{:e 1}
         {:e 2}]
     :f 1}
 :g {:h {:i 4}}}
```

Essentially the same as Elasticsearch's `fields` parameter. The format of the paths argument can be something else, this is just the first idea.

I tried two different solutions

1. Go through the entire map and checking if the full path of the current element is in the given paths. I can't figure out how to handle lists of maps so that they are kept as lists of maps.
2. Creating `select-keys` statements from the given paths but again I run into problems with lists of maps - and especially trying to resolve paths of varying depths that have some common depth.

I looked at spectre but I didn't see anything that would do this. Any `map` or `postwalk` based solution I come up with turns into something incredibly convoluted at some point. I must be thinking about this the wrong way.

If there's a way to do this with raw json, that would be fine as well. Or even a Java solution.

Comment: What happens when multiple paths start with the same keyword? What happens if a path doesn't exist? Because nil propagation is the default, is that what you want?

Comment: In the example there are two paths that start the same `[:b :c :e]` and `[:b :f]`. Basically you would find the deepest common element. Although I'm open to it being defined as `[:b [:f [:c :e]]]]` if it makes it easier to handle. `nil` for a missing path is the desired outcome.

Comment: Well, my lunch break is almost over but I'll try to code up a solution tonight if someone doesn't beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this problem would be to generate a set of all subpaths that you accept and then write a recursive function that traverses the data structure and keeps track of the path to the current node. The code that accomplishes that does not need to be very long:

```
(defn select-paths-from-set [current-path path-set data]
  (cond
    (map? data) (into {}
                      (remove nil?)
                      (for [[k v] data]
                        (let [p (conj current-path k)]
                          (if (contains? path-set p)
                            [k (select-paths-from-set p path-set v)]))))
    (sequential? data) (mapv (partial select-paths-from-set current-path path-set) data)
    :default data))

(defn select-paths [data paths]
  (select-paths-from-set []
                         (into #{}
                               (mapcat #(take-while seq (iterate butlast %)))
                               paths)
                         data))

(select-paths {:a 1
               :b {:c [{:d 1 :e 1} 
                       {:d 2 :e 2}]
                   :f 1}
               :g {:h {:i 4 :j [1 2 3]}}}
              [[:a] 
               [:b :c :e]
               [:b :f]
               [:g :h :i]])
;; => {:a 1, :b {:c [{:e 1} {:e 2}], :f 1}, :g {:h {:i 4}}}
```

Comment: This works like charm! And it's beautifully concise.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to accomplish your goal.  The automatic processing implied for the sequence under `[:b :c]` is also problematic.

You can get partway there using the [Tupelo Forest](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc) library. See the [Lightning Talk video](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM) from Clojure/Conj 2017.

I did some additional work in data destructuring that you may find useful building the `tupelo.core/destruct` macro (see examples [here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/cljc/tst/tupelo/core.cljc#L2678)).  You could follow a similar outline to build a recursive solution to your specific problem.

A related project is [Meander](https://github.com/noprompt/meander).  I have worked on my own version which is like a generalized version of `tupelo.core/destruct`. Given data like this

```
(def skynet-widgets [{:basic-info   {:producer-code "Cyberdyne"}
                      :widgets      [{:widget-code      "Model-101"
                                      :widget-type-code "t800"}
                                     {:widget-code      "Model-102"
                                      :widget-type-code "t800"}
                                     {:widget-code      "Model-201"
                                      :widget-type-code "t1000"}]
                      :widget-types [{:widget-type-code "t800"
                                      :description      "Resistance Infiltrator"}
                                     {:widget-type-code "t1000"
                                      :description      "Mimetic polyalloy"}]}
                     {:basic-info   {:producer-code "ACME"}
                      :widgets      [{:widget-code      "Dynamite"
                                      :widget-type-code "c40"}]
                      :widget-types [{:widget-type-code "c40"
                                      :description      "Boom!"}]}])
```

You can search and extract data using a template like this:

```
    (let [root-eid (td/add-entity-edn skynet-widgets)
          results  (td/match
                     [{:basic-info   {:producer-code ?}
                       :widgets      [{:widget-code      ?
                                       :widget-type-code wtc}]
                       :widget-types [{:widget-type-code wtc
                                       :description      ?}]}])]
      (is= results
        [{:description "Resistance Infiltrator" :widget-code "Model-101" :producer-code "Cyberdyne" :wtc "t800"}
         {:description "Resistance Infiltrator" :widget-code "Model-102" :producer-code "Cyberdyne" :wtc "t800"}
         {:description "Mimetic polyalloy" :widget-code "Model-201" :producer-code "Cyberdyne" :wtc "t1000"}
         {:description "Boom!" :widget-code "Dynamite" :producer-code "ACME" :wtc "c40"}])))
```

This code is working (see [here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/tupelo-data/blob/master/test/cljc/tst/tupelo/data.cljc#L1394)) but it needs more polish. You could use it as a guide to building a generalized `select-paths` function.

---

Can you add any details on how this problem arose or the specific context? That may point to ideas for an alternate solution.

Comment: Meander looks promising. In my case the schema of the structure is known which helps. I would have liked a general solution of course, but I realise it's a big ask. Need to play around with these, thanks!

Comment: As for the origin of the problem: I have a rest api that returns different lists of large json objects. I want to provide a way to filter the massive json response since different clients are interested in different subsets of the data

Comment: @siltalau graphQL?